# Как в django сделать проверку нажатие на кнопку?

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django

У меня есть код html, в котором мне нужно узнать какую кнопку нажал пользователь и сделать определенные действия.
HTML:

```html
<div class="w3-show-inline-block">
    <div class="w3-bar">
        <h4 class="w3-wide">Сортировать по:
        <button name="sort_complexity_ascending" class="w3-button w3-black">сложности от 1 до 5</button>
        <button name="sort_complexity_descending" class="w3-button w3-black">сложности от 5 до 1</button>
        <button name="sort_alphabet_ascending" class="w3-button w3-black">алфавиту от А до Я</button>
        <button name="sort_alphabet_descending" class="w3-button w3-black">алфавиту от Я до А</button></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py:

```py
if request.method == 'GET':
    if request.GET.get("sort_alphabet_ascending"):
        history = sort_alphabet_ascending(history)
    elif request.GET.get("sort_alphabet_descending"):
        history = sort_alphabet_descending(history)
    elif request.GET.get("sort_complexity_descending"):
        history = sort_complexity_descending(history)
    elif request.GET.get("sort_complexity_ascending"):
        history = sort_complexity_ascending(history)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путь web-разработчика должен начинаться с понимания, что сайт - это на самом деле не одно приложение, а два, написанные на разных языках, работающие на разных компьютерах, в разном окружении и в разное время.

В случае Django работу сайта можно разбить на следующие этапы:

1. Пользователь запустил браузер и ввёл адрес сайта
2. Браузер установить tcp-соединение с сервером
3. Браузер отправил в соединение http-запрос
4. Сервер в ответ на запрос запустил соответствующий python-скрипт
5. Python-cкрипт в процессе работы сформировал некоторое количество
   текста и отправил в tcp-соединение
6. **Python-скрипт завершил работу**
7. Браузер принял весь текст от сервера и **закрыл соединение**
8. Браузер проанализировал полученных текст и нарисовал пользователю
   страницу

Все дальнейшие действия пользователя будут обрабатываться только в браузере, самим браузером и\или javascript'ом. И javascript, и браузер будут работать с теми данными, которые получили от сервера. Если понадобятся другие данные или нужно будет какие-то данные серверу передать, придётся повторить операции из списка выше, или с помощью отправки формы или с помощью ajax-запроса.

Отсюда ответ на ваш вопрос, если хотите чтобы Django отреагировал на нажатие кнопки, придётся отправить ему http-запрос, или с помощью формы или с помощью AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

if 'save' in request.POST:
print('save')

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1485804/edit)».