# Передать данные из js в django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Как передать из django в html я понял, нужно в views.py в context добавить то, что хотим передать.

```
def index(request):
context = {'str': 'hello world'}
return render(request, 'liner/editor.html', context)
```

и в html вытащить с помощью {{ str }}.
Так вот вопрос, как сделать обратное? Чтобы из js/html передать данные в django

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в django сделать проверку нажатие на кнопку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1006684/204271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вы не указали что вам конкретно надо получить/передать.
Вот пример получения данных из формы с помощью POST запроса

view.py

```
def chat(request):
   results = "her"
   if "your_name" in request.POST:
      results = request.POST["your_name"]
   return render(request, 'poll/chat.html',context={'name':results})
```

chat.html

```
<form action="/chat" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<label for="your_name">Your question: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
```

и вывода на странице

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Можете еще показать, как из js высылать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Django работает на сервере. Т.е. сервер отдал данные на клиент(ваш браузер). Чтоб передать данные обратно вам нужно снова сделать запрос на сервер. Т.е. обновить страницу или отправить запрос с помощью js. Почитайте про это [XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) или ajax.